# How so I sample from a subset?

Tags: probability

So my problem is that I have a distribution and a population.
My population is: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
The distribution is: [0.1, 0, 0.3, 0.6, 0], for each corresponding element.
So for example 1 has a 0.1 chance occurring.

Now my problem is that at any time I am given a subset of the population.
So for example I can have: [2,4]. But I want to keep the same distribution.
So that means the distribution would be [0, 0.6], but this doesn't make sense.. It doesn't add up to one.

Is there a way to keep the same probabilities ? I hope I am making sense.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to sample according to the distribution. Then you have no chance to sample [2] because it has 0 probability to be sampled.

Also, you should think about sample size. You cannot have the same distribution if you will sample only one element. The more elements you have in subsample, the more your distribution will be similar to the initial one.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, you may need to check the definition of **conditional probability**.

Suppose your new sample is chosen from a subset like A={2,4}, then the probability of A=2 would be 
$$
Pr = \frac{0}{0+0.6} = 0.
$$

Hope this could help you.

Comment: is this the bayes rule you shared ?

Comment: @test I won't call it bayes here, although bayesian formula is indeed from the conditional probability :) Here it is just a frequentist problem.